# Fixed 500 Error in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

Note: I didn't do this install of Wordpress, it was here when I get here. Basically, whoever set it up is using it as a CMS and it's structured like so:

index->mainIndex.php
/weblog/ ->archives.php

If we try to access a Permalink from the /weblog portion of the site, we get a 500 error. I've tried every .htaccess trick in the book, I can't seem to get to the bottom of this.

View the site here: [gamedesk.org](http://www.gamedesk.org) , check out the weblog tab. Any permalink (In the titles) will throw a 500. I've tried every permutation of permalink from the admin panel, as well.

EDIT: Solved. Checked the Apache server logs- A misplaced semicolon was tossing an error, but PHP wasn't set up to handle errors so Apache tossed a 500 instead. Always check the logs, kids!

Comment: do you have any extra plugins installed for SEO or rewrite urls? also try to visit wp-admin/options-permalink.php after you login and then check weblog post afterwards. in case if this does not work can you upload a snapshot for your .htaccess and option-permlink.php page

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do this in the beginning of your first php file:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
```